First .bat script to update a git branch
update-branch.bat is my first batch script. Its current behavior is

update-branch updates the current branch
update-branch foo updates branch foo

By update branch, I mean

checkout master
pull origin master
checkout branch
rebase branch on master
force push branch

Please review my first script for the aspects below. I would appreciate any suggestions.
Style

Should I lowercase commands? (e.g. SET, DO)?
Should I lowercase var names? (e.g. BRANCH)?

Misc.

Is SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION necessary?

Questions

How can I add an optional -p flag so that script only pauses when the -p flag is passed? To support the following:

update-branch -p
update-branch -p foo
update-branch foo -p

update-branch.bat
@echo off

@REM optional branch argument
SET BRANCH=%1
IF NOT DEFINED BRANCH (
    @REM if opt arg is not given, use current branch
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN ('git branch --show-current') DO (SET BRANCH=%%g)
)

@REM newline
SET n=^&echo(
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET n4=!n!!n!!n!!n!

echo Update '%BRANCH%'?
pause
echo %n4%

IF %BRANCH%==master (
    git pull origin master
    EXIT /B
)

echo Update master?
pause
git checkout master
git pull origin master
echo %n4%

echo Rebase '%BRANCH%' on master?
pause
git checkout %BRANCH%
git rebase master
echo %n4%

REM if any, resolve merge conflicts, then 'git rebase --continue'

echo Force push '%BRANCH%'?
pause
git push --force


Can you [edit] your post to clarify what you mean by "update a branch"?

@GregBurghardt done!

If you want a review of the newest code, rather than adding it to the question, post it as a follow up question with a link back to this question. Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. What to do after the question has been answered.

I can't say much about the batch file aspect, but a few words about git:
You don't need to checkout master in order to update it. Instead you can use
git fetch origin master:master

You should also avoid a "pure" force push. Instead there is --force-with-lease which avoids overwriting changes by other people.

If I do git fetch origin master:master, does that update the ref/head for the master branch?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78769882/13881506

@joseville Yes, it does, if its a fast-forward. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts . Note that in that other question of yours you asked about pull, not fetch.
